# How to concatenate two dataframes when there are different number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:
`df1` looks like below:

```
A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
2    6    8    1    3    9    2    3
```

`df2` looks like below:

```
A    C    D    G
3    2    4    9
```

Now, I want to add the data of `df2` to `df1`. But, I want to insert "N/A" for `df2` when any column which exists in `df1` but not present in `df2`. You can think, my I want something like below:

```
A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
2    6    8    1    3    9    2    3
3   N/A   2    4   N/A  N/A   9    N/A
```

Can anyone please help, how can I do this?

Comment: merge? `df1.merge(df2,how='outer')` or `df.append(df2)`

Comment: @anky Would be a concat, not a merge, right? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: @NickODell in this usecase, an outer merge should suffice as well?  set index (col A) with concat would work too I agree

Comment: @NickODell added an append dupe as well incase the OP wants to concat based on index, Thanks for pointing that

Comment: `df.append(df2)` works in my case. Thank you.